# In USB 2.0, what's the maximum delay between SETUP and DATA0 packets?

Tags: usb, usb-device

In the setup stage of a USB control transfer, the host sends both the SETUP and the DATA0 packets. Assuming that the device has received the SETUP packet, how long should it wait for the DATA0 packet? I wasn't successful at finding that information in the USB 2.0 spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Assuming that the device has received the SETUP packet, how long should it wait for the DATA0 packet?

There is no timeout here. The device must retain setup information until either

- the control transfer has finished
- another SETUP packet arrives (e.g. due to bus errors)
- USB Reset/Disconnect is detected

Comment: USB 2.0 specs Figure 8-32?

Comment: @Ale..chenski well this figure actually mentions a timeout for the DATA packet, which is what made me wonder in the first place.